# Training seq2seq translation model with one source and multiple target

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing, recurrent-neural-networks, machine-translation, seq2seq

So basically I'm training a sequence to sequence model that translates English sentences to Arabic sentences. I'm using the data provided by [Anki @ manythings](http://www.manythings.org/anki/). I realized that some of the sentences in English (source) have multiple sentences in Arabic (target), for example:

This is one case, where the Arabic harakat are not shown but the idea is that the same word has different translations (yes in arabic the first, fourth and fifth are not the same translations).

[image: example-1]

A better example is the following one:

[image: example-2]

I'm not sure how to deal with these cases, should I reduce the data and keep one translation, or should I have for each source key a list of target values. Any advice or "tips & tricks" in preparing the data before training translation models?